Exploring Perfect Cubic Numbers: When Does the Product of Proper Divisors Equal $N^3$?
I’ve been delving into an intriguing property related to perfect numbers and their proper divisors. Specifically, I’m investigating numbers  $N$  for which the product of their proper divisors equals the cube of the number itself. Formally, I’m looking for integers  $N$  that satisfy the following equation:
$$
\prod_{\substack{d \mid N \\ d \neq N}} d = N^3
$$
Initial Findings:

$N = 6$ :
•   Proper Divisors:  $1, 2, 3$
•   Product of Divisors:  $1 \times 2 \times 3 = 6 $
•    $N^3 = 6^3 = 216$
•   Observation:
To balance the equation, I considered raising each divisor to the power of $2$ and then multiplying by  $N$:

$$(1^2 \times 2^2 \times 3^2) \times 6 = 1 \times 4 \times 9 \times 6 = 216 = 6^3$$
This adjustment satisfies the equation:
$$
\prod_{\substack{d \mid N \\ d \neq N}} d^2 \times N = N^3
$$

Testing Other Numbers:
•    $N = 28$ :
•   Proper Divisors:  $1, 2, 4, 7, 14 $
•   Product of Divisors:  $1 \times 2 \times 4 \times 7 \times 14 = 784 $
•    $N^3 = 28^3 = 21952 $
•   Observation:

$$(1^2 \times 2^2 \times 4^2 \times 7^2 \times 14^2) \times 28 = 1 \times 4 \times 16 \times 49 \times 196 \times 28 = 21952 = 28^3$$
This also satisfies the adjusted equation.

Another test:
•   $N = 496$ :
•   Proper Divisors:  $1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 31, 62, 124, 248 $
•   Product of Divisors:  $1 \times 2 \times 4 \times 8 \times 16 \times 31 \times 62 \times 124 \times 248 = 488,552,96 $
•    $N^3 = 496^3 = 121,287,296 $
•   Observation:

$$(1^2 \times 2^2 \times 4^2 \times 8^2 \times 16^2 \times 31^2 \times 62^2 \times 124^2 \times 248^2) \times 496 \neq 496^3$$
The equation does not hold for  $N = 496$.
Pattern Observed:
• The adjusted formula:
$$
\prod_{\substack{d \mid N \\ d \neq N}} d^2 \times N = N^3
$$
holds true for certain small even perfect numbers like  $N = 6$  and  $N = 28$ , but fails for larger ones like  $N = 496$.
Questions:

Is  $N = 6$  the only even perfect number that satisfies the original condition  $\prod d = N^3$  without any exponent adjustments?
Are there any known classes of numbers (possibly beyond perfect numbers) that satisfy the condition  $\prod d^a = N^3$  for some exponent  $a$ ?
Can this property be extended or modified to include a broader set of numbers, perhaps by introducing additional factors or constraints?
What theoretical insights can be drawn about the relationship between the product of divisors and the cube of the number, especially in the context of perfect numbers?

Additional Considerations:

Odd Perfect Numbers:
Since the existence of odd perfect numbers is still an open question in number theory, I’m curious if any hypothetical properties of such numbers might influence or relate to this cubic condition.
Factorial-Based Exponents:
I experimented with assigning factorial-based exponents to the divisors to balance the equation, but it didn’t yield consistent results beyond  $N = 6$  and  $N = 28$ .

Conclusion:
This exploration reveals a unique property for specific even perfect numbers, highlighting the intricate balance between a number and its divisors. I'm eager to hear thoughts, insights, or references that might shed light on whether this is a coincidental occurrence or part of a deeper mathematical phenomenon.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Note that while MathJax does work on MSE, the \[ \] notation from Latex doesn't. Stick with $ and $$.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. If you look up how even perfect numbers are expressed in terms of Mersenne primes, you can compute the product of the factors.

$N=\prod p_i^{k_i}$ will have proper factors that multiply to $N^3$ when $\prod(k_i+1)=8$
Note that this requires each $k_i$ be odd and $\le 7$; $i\le 3$. You can have a perfect seventh power of a prime, or a prime times the cube of another prime, or the product of three distinct primes.
$\prod(k_i+1)=8$ represents the total number of factors of $N$ including $1,N$. Omitting $N$ itself and noting that $1$ does not affect the product, The remaining $6$ factors consist of three groups of two factors that multiply to $N$, affording a final product of $N^3$
Example: $2^7=128$ with proper factors $1,2,4,8,16,32,64$. Note that $2\cdot 64=4\cdot 32=8\cdot 16=128$. The product of the proper factors is $1\cdot 128\cdot 128\cdot 128=128^3$

This is a solution
to a generalization of
the problem in
the first paragraph,
ignoring the stuff
about perfect numbers.
If $P(n)=\prod_{d|n}d$ then
$P(n)=n^{d(n)/2}$
where $d(n)$
is the number of divisors of $n$.
A proof is at
Product of Divisors of some $n$ proof.
Therefore, if $Q(n)$
is the product of
the proper divisors of $n$,
then
$Q(n)=P(n)/n
=n^{d(n)/2-1}$.
If $Q(n)=n^m$,
$m=3$ here,
then
$d(n)/2-1=m$
so $d(n)=2m+2$.
If $n=\prod p_i^{a_i}$
then
$d(n)=\prod(a_i+1)$,
so we want
$\prod(a_i+1)=2m+2$.
If $m=3$ then
$\prod(a_i+1)=8$
so the possible values of
the $a_i$ are
$(7), (1, 3), (1, 1, 1)$.
So solutions are,
$p^7, p^3q, pqr$
for primes $p, q, r$.

Looking at the formula for
$P(n)$,
I see that it
can not be true
when $n$ is a perfect square
since $d(n)$ is odd
because each $a_i$ is even so
$\prod(a_i+1)$ is odd.
I am looking into this case.
This does not affect this answer
since $d(n)=2m+2$ is even.

Actually, $P(n)
=n^{d(n)/2}$ is true even for
square $n$ because it can
then be written
$P(n)=(\sqrt{n})^{d(n)}$.
